# Foreach Loop not working in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, parse-error

I'm trying to run a foreach loop in php to go through each line of a csv file, I actually got the setup for this loop from another post on stackoverflow (but it's also described the same on php.net).

My code is:

```
$csvFile = file('MajorCourses.csv')

foreach($csvFile as &$line)
{
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line)
}
```

And the php file is in the same directory as my php file, but I get this error:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\wamp2\www\advisingApp.php on line 23"

I'm not sure why it's "unexpected", I'm new to php. But the loop is in php tags.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `file();`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semi colon at the end of your code.

use this instead.

```
$csvFile = file('MajorCourses.csv');

foreach($csvFile as &$line)
{
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is "unexpected" because you're missing semicolons at the ends of your statements.

This line:

```
$csvFile = file('MajorCourses.csv')
```

should be:

```
$csvFile = file('MajorCourses.csv');
```

And:

```
$data[] = str_getcsv($line)
```

Should be:

```
$data[] = str_getcsv($line);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I can't believe I was that stupid haha

Answer (score 1):

And typo here:

```php
$csvFile = file('MajorCourses.csv')
```

should be:

```php
$csvFile = file('MajorCourses.csv');
```

semicolon missing.

This was indicated by the "unexpected 'foreach' " in the error message. If you get an unexpected error,you should check the code in front of the unexpected.

Comment: @Dave ahh. missed that second one and too slow ;)